# Centered and aligned left - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, text

I'm trying to figure out how to have a list of items **centered** in the page but **aligned left** so they're flush. I'm using bootstrap. 
Example:
[image]

I'd like the text in the center of the page - aligned left

```html
<ul class='text-center'>
 <li class='text-left'> Short Item #1 </li>
 <li class='text-left'> Much Longer Item #2 </li>
 <li class='text-left'> Short Item #3 </li>
 <li class='text-left'> Much Much Longer Item #3 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It is really unclear what you want. Do you want to remove default `padding-left` of `<ul>`s? Do you want to remove the `list-style-type`? Do you want your `<li>`s to only stretch a percentage of their parent `<ul>` and have equal margins left and right? Do you want them aligned in a single row? Do you want the `list-style-position` set to `inside`? What does *"flush"* mean in this context?

Comment: I'd like the text in the center of the page - aligned left

Comment: Lilke [this](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/axmjm2sh/) or like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/axmjm2sh/1/)?

Comment: The 2nd one is perfect

Comment: I suggest setting a background on `<ul>` so the alignment is visible. As in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/axmjm2sh/2/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution is specific to Bootstrap 4, but allows you to center an element respective of content-determined width:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row bg-light">
    <div class="col-auto mx-auto">
      <ul class="bg-secondary text-light">
      <li>Short Item #1</li>
      <li>Much Longer Item #2 </li>
      <li>Short Item #3</li>
      <li>Much Much Longer Item #3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `.col-auto` class also accepts breakpoints, so you could enhance responsiveness by forcing different column behaviors at different breakpoints.  The `mx-auto` class forces the left and right margins to be even, resulting in centering the column on your screen.

Answer (score 2):

Edited so that it resembles OP's picture:

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}

.flex-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.text-center {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, harum maiores. Ullam illo consequuntur eum ipsum fugiat, quidem pariatur quibusdam facilis dolores omnis voluptas similique quos commodi incidunt nesciunt error!</p>

<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <ul class='text-center'>
      <li class='text-left'> Short Item #1 </li>
      <li class='text-left'> Much Longer Item #2 </li>
      <li class='text-left'> Short Item #3 </li>
      <li class='text-left'> Much Much Longer Item #3 </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus ea minus sequi placeat eaque at nobis numquam reiciendis explicabo veniam illum consectetur, quis illo consequatur consequuntur! Excepturi nulla molestiae temporibus.</p>
```

Comment: Removing the element from document flow was not required. Why would you do that?

Comment: What element did I remove? I'm not sure what you mean. I updated my answer and also centered the `ul` vertically. It wasn't clear that you wanted that too. :)

Comment: `position:absolute` removes the element from document flow and it has not been required. It has the potential to become a problem for anyone using your code. I only want **that** too if *"that"* is quality and it refers to answers. :)

Comment: If you still don't understand what I'm referring to, see [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/mtx0z0oL/).

Comment: Understood, but in that case how would centering the element vertically make sense? What about [this](https://jsfiddle.net/mtx0z0oL/1/)?

Comment: Vertical centering would make sense if the parent has a set height (or a resulting height, say from being a stretched flex item and height is set by a sibling flex child). You answered deciding the centering should be done inside closest positioned parent (or viewport), regardless of any other content (possibly because no other content was provided - but that doesn't necessarily mean your solution is usable). I hope you don't mind me pointing it out. :)

Comment: Simplest fix around the "problem" is to [position the parent and give it height](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/mtx0z0oL/2/). But you need to make sure the parent is taller than the content. I don't necessarily agree with this fix. It would be better not to use `position:absolute` in the first place.

Comment: No worries, I like that you're challenging me to improve the answer! I thought about giving it a height as well, but like you said, you don't always know how much height the content needs, especially with a list. I just looked at your example, that was exactly my next step, to put it in another container that has a set height with a position relative ;) Thanks for the push for quality ;)

Comment: In fact, since information about context was not provided, it should be asked from OP, not assumed and only then should an answer be provided. Otherwise, we can only assume the content **is** vertically centered in the parent, because the parent has the same height as the content. You're welcome. :)

Comment: If the answer is not that specific, I would assume OP already has a plan for using that code and knows how to use it. Anyways, I updated my answer. :)